# hiding nicescroll after replacing the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, nicescroll

I am using nice scroll in my application. I have given like:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="grid1"></div>
    <div id="grid2" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

I have a button, in button click event,
           I gave like, `$("#grid1").hide();$("#grid2").show();`
  I have defined nicescroll like:

```
 $(".k-grid-content").niceScroll({ cursorwidth: "7px", cursorcolor: "#d7d7d7" });
```

After button click event, content is replacing but still on hover,Two nicescrollers are displaying.one is  for the previous grid content and present grid content. Can any one tell whats is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Nicescroll doesn't know about content replacement, I guess after content is replaced you need to call `resize` function like this:

```
$(".k-grid-content").getNiceScroll().resize();
```

It should refresh bounds which nicescroll captured for it's inner needs.

Comment: You can try hide it if you need: `$(".k-grid-content").getNiceScroll().hide();`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use **iscroll** to your application instead of nicescroll. It will give you smooth scrolling as well as its easy to implement.